# Heroku "failed to compile Multipack app"のエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

まだプログラミングを勉強し始めて半年なのですが、
Heroku+Rails+Gruntのデプロイをしようと思っております。

先日こちらの記事（http://qiita.com/icb54615/items/e5d4db164c5002e4b183）を教えていただいたのですが、

```
    $ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 24, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (24/24), 3.24 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 24 (delta 14), reused 17 (delta 8)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/getgamba/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt-compass.git

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。

アドバイスをいただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

/root/.buildpacks

```
https://github.com/getgamba/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt-compass.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

/root/front/package.json

```
    {
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.7.3",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-connect-proxy": "^0.1.11",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^0.2.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.10.1",
    "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-ngmin": "^0.0.3",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-rails-server": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt-shell-spawn": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^2.1.1",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^1.7.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.1.3",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.2.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^0.4.0",
    "source-map": "^0.1.37",
    "time-grunt": "^0.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

わたしも同じエラーがでていましたが解決しましたので共有します。

https://github.com/getgamba/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt-compass/blob/master/bin/detect
上記のnodejsのbuildpackのコードを見るとnodejsのアプリはclientという名前のディレクトリをdetectします。なのでフロントエンドのアプリを入れているディレクトリの名前をfrontからclientに変更すればなおると思います。

追記

herokuのmulti-buildpackは公式でサポートされているようでhttps://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app
こちらの方法を使うといいかもしれません｡
あと､package.jsonはdevDependenciesだけではなくdependenciedsにも依存関係を書かなければデプロイしたときにインストールしてくれません｡